# Format of text in a database for weka

Tags: java, database, weka

Does the text in a database that is used to feed a `weka.core.Instances` object need to conform to a certain format? When I try to build a classifier with a `weka.core.Instances` object that only contains unformatted text (fed from a database via `weka.experiment.InstanceQuery.query.retrieveInstances()` ) as its non-class attributes I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main"
weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException:
    weka.classifiers.functions.SMO: Cannot handle numeric class!    at
    weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)     at
    weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)     at
    weka.core.Capabilities.test(Unknown Source)     at
    weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Unknown Source)     at
    weka.classifiers.functions.SMO.buildClassifier(Unknown Source)  at
    Test.main(Test.java:135)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this numeric attribute is not supposed to be class attribute. Your exception gives that in google search as [first hit](https://list.scms.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2009-September/045483.html). Can you give output of following code.

```
    Instances data = null;

    try {
        DatabaseUtils utils = new DatabaseUtils();

        InstanceQuery query = new InstanceQuery();

        query.setUsername(username);
        query.setPassword(password);
        query.setQuery(pSql);

        data = query.retrieveInstances();
        data.setRelationName(pInstanceRelationName);


        if (data.classIndex() == -1)
        {
             data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
        }
                    // this line will print out your header + data. 
                    // add your header information to your question.
        System.out.println(data)
    } 

        catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```